# How to populate bootstrap grids with JSON data obtained from fetch() in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I want to populate JSON data into bootstrap grid system.
JSON response:

```
{
  "_id": "5a63051735aaddd30d1d89f8",
  "id": 45,
  "season": 2008,
  "city": "Bangalore",
  "team1": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
  "team2": "Delhi Daredevils",
  "toss_winner": "Delhi Daredevils",
  "toss_decision": "field",
  "result": "normal",
  "dl_applied": 0,
  "winner": "Delhi Daredevils",
  "win_by_runs": 0,
  "win_by_wickets": 5,
  "player_of_match": "SP Goswami",
  "venue": "M Chinnaswamy Stadium",
  "umpire1": "SJ Davis",
  "umpire2": "GA Pratapkumar",
  "umpire3": ""
}
```

The JSON response returns around 577 JSON objects now I want to populate above JSON data into bootstrap grid system.

main.js

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            matches: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(matches => this.setState({matches}, () => console.log('Matches fetched...', matches)));
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[0].season}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavenderblush;">{this.state.matches[5].season}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[8].season}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In above code I am trying to display `matches[0].season` `matches[5].season`
`matches[8].season` but shows error see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to wait for `setState()` to be called, which would in turn populate the `matches` array.  Remember that because you're using `componentDidMount`, as well as making an **asynchronous** call to fetch data, the component will have already rendered with `this.state.matches` set to an empty array.

Here's a quick [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpOYrw?editors=0010).

This may help as well - [Where to Fetch Data](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/)

Comment: Why I am getting this error -> https://imgur.com/a/YjULD here is my code -> https://imgur.com/a/5jhaJ and the JSON response is like this -> https://imgur.com/a/16QSN

Comment: please tell me what changes should I make in my code see above screenshots of imgur link

Comment: I think I am getting error because of not getting correct response from REST api endpoint. Can you tell me what should I do in my code because in your code you have done `matches.data` which is not possible in my code as I have created API endpoint.

Comment: You can comment out the `<div>`s and check the returned value. As long as its an array of objects (since this is how you're using it), it shouldn't matter. Try wrapping your divs in a conditional statement - `this.state.matches.length > 0`.

Comment: Yes if I add conditional statement it works fine but if I do not add it then it again throws error why does this happen ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the component will first render with an empty array. It is during this initial render that your application will crash because you're referencing data that's just not there yet. Hope that helps.

Comment: So because of `constructor` it render's empty array and then after `componentdidmount` it displays the populate data am I right ? If possible please suggest me some tutorials/ resources where I can learn more about this concept.

Answer (score 0):

We can populate bootstrap grids by using `fetch()` see below code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('api/matches')
    .then(res => res.json()) // It resolves the promise with a JSON object
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches: res,
      })
    })
}
```

Also in render function add conditional statement:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.matches.length === 0) {
    return <div>>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[0].season}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavenderblush;">{this.state.matches[5].season}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[8].season}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```